# How would I translate this sqlite query into a postgresql query in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite

I am trying to filter my posts and I grab them using this query.

```
@posts = Post.all.includes(:course).where("courses.name IN (#{@user.courses.map(&:name).collect { |s| "'#{s}'"  }.join(',') })").references(:course).order("posts.created_at DESC")
```

I am not familiar with postgresql and know there are some differences. How do I change this to query in postgres?

Comment: Have you tried running that query? It might just work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query will work as it is. But you can modify the query to avoid the unnecessary operations you are doing:

```
@posts = 
  Post.all.includes(:course).where("courses.name IN (?)", @user.courses.map(&:name)).order("posts.created_at DESC")
```

Rails will take care of joining the values in this array  `@user.courses.map(&:name)`

You don't need to do it manually.

Comment: You are right, it works, I was switching to postgres as I posted this question, but Im glad you show me this simplified query, thank you!